# How to find all integers $a,b > 1$ satisfying $b \mid a^2+1$ and $a^2 \mid b^3+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Let $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $a,b>1$, and such that $b \mid a^2+1$ and $a^2 \mid b^3+1$. Find all such $a,b$.

I found $a=3,b=2$. Are there any other solutions? Thank you.

yesterday  I have find this
[image]

since $a,b>1$ so $(a,b)=(3,2)$ or $(a,b)=(3,5)

Comment: $a=3$, $b=5$ is another.

Comment: oh,Yeah,Thank you @GerryMyerson

Comment: can find all $a,b$?

Comment: oh,I have solve it,Thank you everyone.this proble have only two solution:$a=3,b=5$ or $a=3,b=2$

Comment: Does $b=-1$, $a=$ *whatever you want* not count? Or is that cheating?

Comment: If you have solved it, please write up your solution and accept it.

Comment: @user1729:  OP did say $b\gt 1$ but it is a good thought.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, missed that. Just saw the $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Just solved for $\mathbb{Z}$ and saw "$a,~b\in \mathbb{Z};~a,~b>1$". Dude, why don't you just write $\mathbb{N}$?..

Comment: @math110 Since you have not posted your solution for $10$ hours, I have gone ahead and posted my solution.

Comment: Thank you,my frend,@Ivan Loh ,your methods same as me,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $(a, b)$ is a solution with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, a, b>1$. If $b=a^2+1$, then $a^2 \mid (b^3+1)=(a^2+1)^3+1$ so $a^2 \mid 2$, so $a=1$, a contradiction. Thus $\frac{a^2+1}{b}$ is a positive integer $>1$. Note that $a^2 \mid (\frac{a^2+1}{b})^3(b^3+1)=(a^2+1)^3+(\frac{a^2+1}{b})^3$, so $a^2 \mid 1+(\frac{a^2+1}{b})^3$, so if $(a, b)$ is a solution, so is $(a, \frac{a^2+1}{b})$. Note that at least $1$ of $b, \frac{a^2+1}{b}$ is $\leq a$. (Otherwise $a^2+1=b(\frac{a^2+1}{b}) \geq (a+1)^2$, which is impossible) It thus suffices to consider the case where $b \leq a$, since any solution with $b>a$ can be mapped to a solution with $b \leq a$ by above.

If $b=a$, then $b\mid a^2+1=b^2+1$, so $b \mid 1$, so $b=1$, a contradiction. Thus $a \geq b+1$. Write $b^3+1=ca^2$, then $b \mid c(a^2+1)=(b^3+1)+c$ so $b \mid c+1$. Thus $c+1 \geq b$. Therefore $b^3+1=ca^2 \geq (b-1)(b+1)^2=b^3+b^2-b-1$ so $0 \geq b^2-b-2=(b-2)(b+1)$, so $b \leq 2$, so $b=2$. Thus $a^2 \mid (2^3+1)=9$, so $a=3$.

Finally, all solutions are given by $(a, b)=(3, 2)$ and $(a, b)=(3, \frac{3^2+1}{2})=(3, 5)$. These solutions are easily checked to work.

Comment: Thank you  This very nice methods,+1